# spam tool in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm new in VB.NET , i try to make spam wall (fb) in vb.net so , this my code,

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

         Process.Start("https://graph.facebook.com/" & (TextBox2.Text) & "/photos?url=" & (TextBox3.Text) & "&method=POST&message=" & (TextBox4.Text) & "a&access_token=" & (TextBox1.Text))

    End Sub
End Class
```

after that , i'm click button 1 , and i see new web page in my browser.
so , i want to make if i click button 1 , there no webpage in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

if don't wanna open the browser then use webbrowser control like so

```
Private webbrows As New WebBrowser

private sub form_load(snder......

dim _url as string = "your url that mostly wont work"

webbrows.Navigate(_url)

' if you use vb2010 then you have lambada expressions 

 AddHandler webbrows.DocumentCompleted, Sub(sd As Object, e4 As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

' a check that the page fully loaded                                                    
 If e4.Url.ToString <> _url Then Exit Sub

 sd.dispose()

  End Sub

end sub
```

Comment: then remove the sd.dispose() line

and replace it with webbrows.navigate (_url) and it will repeat endless